# Ordinal logistic regression suign clmm function in R, random effect structure

Tags: r, logistic

I'm running an ordinal logistic regression in R. I have 3 independent categorical variables (each with two levels). I was wondering if there is a similar function to  `step` from the lmerTest package for linear (mixed) models that can be used for determining the random and fixed effect structure when using cumulative link mixed models in R.

So far, I've been using anovas to compare two models, whether the model which included a given random factor could explain the data better, but I would like to know if there is an "easier" and more systematic way to arrive at the best model structure when using a cumulative link mixed model (`clmm`).

Is there a similar function to  `step` analyzing ordinal data using clmm?

Comment: not that I know of.

Comment: Stepwise variable selection is not a valid statistical method.  It will ruin your standard errors among other things.   Pre-specify the model.  And please specify which R package you are using.  I assume it's `ordinal`.

Answer (score 0):

The MuMIn package has the "dredge" command, which defaults to AICc. You can use AICc to compare models, with all the caveats and warnings that go along with it. MuMIn's dredge will work with clmm, clm, and polr.